# Passing Data between middlewares

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have created a couple middlewares, one per specific function, and I want the succeeding middlewares to make use of the data created from the previous middleware, instead of generating it from scratch. Is there a way to do that? I'm not sure if I should mess with `$request` or `$next`.

Comment: You may use Singleton pattern, but i think this is not best way

Comment: What kind of data are you creating in the middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Session::put('key',$value)` method to store data in session and then get it from next middleware by using `Session::get('key')`, or you can pass that data in `$request` object, for example `$request->addCustomField = 'custom field value'` and then you can get it from next middleware by using `$request->addCustomField`.
Hope it will help

Comment: thanks for this! this is actually the approach I took.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [merge](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) function to add to the input:

```
return $next($request->merge(['my_data' => $data]));
```

It's then accessible as `$request->input('my_data')`, for example.

[offsetUnset](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_offsetUnset) can be used to remove the data in the next middleware if need be.

Comment: merge might replace the 'my_data' field though in case that parameter exists in the request.

Comment: Yes, I would expect the developer to know what fields are present before hand and select a well named index so as to not overwrite data.